# Как вытащить данные из сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Всем привет!
Нужно вытащить информацию с сайта.Подробнее: результаты футбольных матчей с сайта [myscore.ru](http://myscore.ru)
Выслушаю любые принадлежности.

Comment: Если нет АПИ, то только ручной парсинг регулярками и тд, с которым связано масса проблем.

Comment: на каком языке программирования-то хоть?
можно и просто сохранить страницу и блокнотом скопировать нужные данные))

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю это на python'е с помощью модуля lxml.html. Точнее, с помощью пары функций из него. Одна называется document_fromstring. Она делает DOM-дерево из ответа http-сервера. Другая же делает к этому дереву xpath-запрос, который возвращает нужный элемент. Общая идея примерно такова:

```
from lxml.html import document_fromstring
doc = document_fromstring(response.text)
tbl = doc.xpath('//table[descendant::tr[position()=1]/th[text()="Заголовок"]]')
```

(Этот код вылавливает из документа такую таблицу, у которой первая строка содержит заголовочную ячейку с текстом "Загловок".)

Answer (score 0):

внимательно изучить сайт.

далее

1. если есть ajax запросы -- изуить и использовать
2. парсить страницу на php скриптом simple_html_dom

все данные они берут с livescore, там можно вроде как на свой сайт такую мутотень сделать...